# Load another form inside the main form panle

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I want to load another form inside the main form panel. Once another form is chosen the main form needs to be removed and the new one should be set to the panel.

**Main Form**

[image]

**Second Form**

[image]

**Code**

```
 this.Wrapper.Controls.Clear();
        this.Wrapper.Visible = true;

        FrmCompany frm = new FrmCompany()
        {
            Width = this.Wrapper.Width,
            Height = this.Wrapper.Height,
            TopLevel = false,
            AutoScroll = true,
            ControlBox = false,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized,
            Style = MetroColorStyle.Default
        };
        this.Wrapper.Controls.Add(frm);

        frm.Left = 0;
        frm.Top = 0;

        frm.Show();
```

Comment: Modify to include a clear question you would like to have answered. Make sure to show any code or describe what you have already tried. The more context you give the better your odds for a quality answer.

Comment: To show a form in content panel, it's enough to set `TopLevel` property of forms to false and set `FormBorderStyle` of them to  None and the add them to center container controls collection and show the form. To remove the form, close it.

Comment: Instead of having multiple forms for each tab, make user controls for each tab they are more suitable for the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to display a form inside a panel then do something like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 newofrm = new Form2();//new instance
        newofrm.TopLevel = false;//allow to added to panel
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(newofrm);// add to panel
        newofrm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;// remove boarder
        newofrm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;// completely fill panel
        newofrm.Show();// show the form
    }
```